# Using .gitignore to ignore a full directory

Tags: git, github

I have created a .gitignore file in the root directory of a project, and I would like to ignore an entire folder and anything that gets place within it.

My .gitgnore file contains only the following:

```
/dir/output/*
```

But everytime I add or modify files within the output directory the changes get tracked. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the first '/' . and you dont need the "/*"

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell git to remove the cache before it starts "listening" to the new ignore. Make sure you commit your changes first and then do the following command:

```
git rm . -r --cached
git add .
git commit -m "what ever message"
```

Comment: I tried this @jhamPac, but still then adds a file i create in the output folder.

Comment: hmmm, and .gitignore is at the root? with correct relative path? did you try removing '/*' at the end?

Comment: how did you create the .gitignore? what kind of editor. its best to use something like vim as opposed to a third party texteditor. it can act weird sometimes if you do.

Comment: its hard to tell without looking at your structure. we may have to take this to chat, if I can't think of anything else within 5 min or so